# How To Add Custom Form With Image File On Customer Dashbaord And Listing Cusotm Form Inquiry Shopify

Tags: shopify

we need to create custom form on customer dashboard and display the all custom form data in customer’s dashboard fo shopify project

please  help  how can add the form display the data

Create page  but is not working